# 500 error when custom controller method fires Action Mailer in Rails (on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gmail, actionmailer

My app sends an email when a button is clicked, this is working fine on development but has a 500 error when testing on Production (Heroku)

The logs point to something to do with the connection to a port or with allowing the custom POST method I've created to enable the trigger but I can't decipher it. Any pointers or help would be very appreciated.

The logs of the failed button click:

```
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] GifMailer#nearby_email: processed outbound mail in 0.7ms
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Delivered mail 5edfb32c2444b_41f5b823695@0f888f21-e8fa-493c-af7e-0e6fd5659d54.mail (2.8ms)
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Date: Tue, 09 Jun 2020 16:05:00 +0000
    - From: jack@xxxx.xxxxx
    - To: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
     - Message-ID: <5edfb32c2444b_41f5b823695@0f888f21-e8fa-493c-af7e-0e6fd5659d54.mail>
     - Subject: Hello in there
     - Mime-Version: 1.0
     - Content-Type: text/html;
     - charset=UTF-8
    - Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
     -
     - Hello in there
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 2.7ms | Allocations: 3021)
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95]
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] app/controllers/gifs_controller.rb:12:in `email'
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Processing by ErrorsController#internal_server_error as HTML
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ZTpQtYnCZwlx9Fy/PWwMES+6CT8kXFoQu8pDr4ok+L1bzbeXsL6ikj8Yof9VJzFUEeVO/84xl3Uc8SOFxjg5cQ==", "gif_email"=>"xxxxxxx@gmail.com"}
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Rendering errors/internal_server_error.html.erb within layouts/errors
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Rendered errors/internal_server_error.html.erb within layouts/errors (Duration: 11.9ms | Allocations: 154)
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Rendered shared/_favicons.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 6)
    [0f392bc6-e18e-4387-a3c1-043c58f6fa95] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (Views: 27.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1742)
```

The controller:

```
    class GifsController < ApplicationController
      protect_from_forgery except: [:email, :show], prepend: true
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
      before_action :set_gif, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

      def email
        @gif_email = params[:gif_email]
        GifMailer.with(gif_email: @gif_email).nearby_email.deliver_now
      end
      helper_method :email
      ...

    end
```

The Mailer:

```
    class GifMailer < ApplicationMailer
        default from: "jack@xxxxxxxx"

        def nearby_email
            @gif_email = params[:gif_email]
            mail(to: @gif_email, content_type: "text/html", subject: "Hello in there", body: "Hello in there", template_path: 'app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb' )
        end

    end
```

production.rb mail settings:

```
    config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
      config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      host = 'xxx.xxxxx'
      config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
        address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
        port:                 587,
        user_name:            ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
        password:             ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
        authentication:       'plain',
        enable_starttls_auto: true,
        openssl_verify_mode: 'none'
      }
```

Relevant routes:

```
    post '/email', to: "gifs#email", as: :hellointhere

      resources :gifs, path: ''
```

Comment: Somewhere it looks like you're trying to connect to localhost which isn't going to work in production. `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25)`

Comment: Doh! Thanks don’t know how I missed that

Comment: So the cause was something specific to the JumpStart Rails platform that I'm using to create the app. In order to rectify I had to sign up for a supported email service instead of Gmail and go through the steps of editing the rails:credentials. Will add a reply incase anyone else comes across the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in the way that the app is configured. I am using the Jumpstart Rails platform which does a lot of the background configuration. Unfortunately it didn't allow me to use Gmail so I had to use another 3rd party email service.

For anyone having the same problem with Jumpstart:

1. Sign up for one of the supported email services, I used Postmark, grab your api key
2. Enter the credentials in rails credentials:edit --environment=production
3. Delete any custom SMTP configuration settings you may have in production.rb
4. Go through the authorisation process of whichever platform you're using
5. Profit